# React Native button not align center

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm including a button inside my native base form, but it is not align in center.

```
<Form>
   ...

   <Item inlineLabel>
      <View style={styles.alignCenter}>
         <Button primary style={styles.btnUpd}><Text> Update </Text></Button>
      </View>
   </Item>
</Form>
```

My styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  alignCenter: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  btnUpd: {
    height: 35,
    marginTop: 4,
    marginBottom: 4,
  }
});
```

I thought I just had to use justifyContent and alignItems center to centralize an object. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `<Body>` tag to set it to center of your screen and for left and right side of screen you could use `<Left>` and `<Right>` like this :

```
<View>
   <Body>
      <Button>
         <Text> Update </Text>
      </Button>
   </Body>
</View>
```